# ISP Upgraded to IPV6 and I can no longer use ping, or other services

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, ipv6

My ISP has been having trouble with their ADSL service for a few months, so my router automatically switches over to use their wireless service.

When on wireless my public IP address is an IPV6 address, and this causes problems with my VPN, which does not support IPV6.  This surprised me, since my laptop which runs the VPN client has both a V4 and V6 address.  Presumably the VPN client is working off the public address?

The biggest surprise however is that I can no longer ping services that I would expect to be able to, e.g. 1.1.1.1, and 8.8.8.8.  Also, I have not been able to curl to some software development sites that I regularly use.

Does the IPV6 public address explain why basic internet utilities (such as ping and curl) are failing?  Or do I need to search for another explanation?

Comment: If they are only giving you an IPv6 address, they should have a NAT64 gateway in place that allows you to reach IPv4-only services. It sounds like they haven't done that.

Comment: By "upgraded to IPv6" do you mean they _disabled_ native IPv4? (The two protocols are _not_ mutually exclusive.) Do not rely solely on online IP address checkers, especially those which don't try to show both kinds of addresses; always check what your router shows in its own status page.

Comment: According to the router, IPV4 is "disconnected"